# How to copy input of one field to another?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code. How do I directly generate a roll number from registration number and branch?
For example, if reg no = 20140087 and branch = BT then in the roll number section , the reg. no and branch would automatically come as 14/BT/_. I only need to provide number in _. 14 would come from 2014 of reg no.

```
<br><br><label>Registration Number: </label>
            <input id="reg" class="text-input" type="text" name="registrationnumber" placeholder="20140087" required>
            <br><br><label>Branch: </label>
            <select style="float:right;">
              <option value="bt">BT</option>
              <option value="ch">CH</option>
              <option value="ce">CE</option>
              <option value="cse">CSE</option>
              <option value="ece">ECE</option>
              <option value="ee">EE</option>
              <option value="it">IT</option>
              <option value="me">ME</option>
              <option value="mme">MME</option>
            </select>

            <br><br><label>Roll No: </label>
            <input id="roll" class="text-input" type="text" name="roll" placeholder="14/IT/11" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this.
If you have regNo is in fix format and than you can write something like this.

```
   var regNo = "20140087";
    var branch = "BT";
    var textBoxVal = regNo.substring(4,2).concat('/',branch,'/');
    $('#roll').val(rollNo)
```

Hopefully this will help you

Comment: What's that val(rolNo) for?

Comment: `$('#myElementID').val(myVal);` sets the value of the element with id=`myElementID` to the value of `myVal`, so here it's setting the value of the roll element to be rollNo

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point for you ([I made up some HTML IDs for the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wvsumua/)).

```
function updateYT() {
  var reg = jQuery('#reg');
  var branch = jQuery('#branch');
  var roll = jQuery('#roll');
  var yt = jQuery('#yt');
  if (!reg || !branch || !roll || !yt) {
    console.log("ERROR: Input field not found!");
    return false;
  }

  var regstr = reg.val();
  if (regstr.length < 4) {
    console.log("Reg string is too short");
    return false;
  } else {
    regstr = regstr.substring(2, 4);
    console.log('REGSTR:');
    console.log(regstr);
  }

  var branchstr = branch.val();
  if (branchstr.length < 2) { // Or whatever is valid
    console.log("Branch string is too short");
    return false;
  }

  var rollstr = roll.val();
  if (rollstr.length < 1) { // Or whatever is valid
    console.log("Roll string is too short");
    return false;
  }

  var ret = branchstr + '/' + regstr + '/' + rollstr;
  yt.val(ret);
}
```

EDIT: Force of habit using jQuery, but you can of course also [use `getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) instead.

Comment: How can I cll this function from the roll input?

Comment: I wrote the fiddle before you posted the rest of your code, but it may still be of use to you.  I've found that in cases like this, it's usually easier to get only the suffix (the "_" part, as you put it) from the user, and then do all the concatenation safely away from user input.  It eliminates a lot of error-checking and trying to force the user to leave the "14/BT/" prefix in there.  If you prefer, you can always display that prefix to the user outside the text box [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/4wvsumua/4/).  As for calling it, in the fiddle it's attached to the inputs' `onchange` event